# UPS settings in Magento 1.6

Tags: magento-1.6

I am using Magento 1.6. Here I want to use UPS shipping method. But in the backend I have not seen userid, pass, access key in UPS settings.

But I have all seen these options in magento 1.9.

So please guide how to set up UPS for magento 1.6

Answer (score 0):

UPS API has been updated since Magento 1.6 release, so UPS module shipped with Magento 1.6 is outdated. The proposed solution would be to upgrade UPS shipping module or use a third-party UPS shipping module from Magento Connect Marketplace:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=UPS+shipping&pl=0